# Could not find/use the right xpath of the Twitter Media button, why?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a Python script (using selenium) that posts `texts` and `media(images)` automatically.

The script works successfully when posting `texts`, but not when try to post an image. The error simply says

`" Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="layers"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"...`

I use the following code to click the Twitter Media button in terms of opening my Windows explorer to prepare for getting into my image folder (see also the highlighted Media button in the image).

```
driver.find_element(by.XPATH, image_xpath).click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element(by.XPATH, image_xpath).send_keys(image)
```

[image: The Twitter Media Button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an input tag available in twitter for uploading file. You can use that locator for uploading file.

Below code is able to tweet an image:

Environment:

**Python** 3.9.5

**OS**: Windows

```
 URL = "https://twitter.com/login"

driver.get(URL)
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "text"))).send_keys("your username")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//*[@role="button"]//following::span[contains(.,"Next")])[2]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("your passowrd")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='LoginForm_Login_Button']"))).click()
sleep(5)

imagePath = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-testid='fileInput']")

imagePath.send_keys("C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\Personal\\selenium.png")

tweetButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-testid='tweetButtonInline']")

tweetButton.click()
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Input  File Tag**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to upload an `image`, if you have an `input tag` with attribute `type` as `file`

you can directly use the `send_keys` to upload an image.

```
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(by.XPATH, image_xpath).send_keys("full file path of image")
```

I would recommend inducing `ExplicitWait`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "image_xpath"))).send_keys("full file path of image")
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Note that you should not click on a button to open a windows pop. Once you are on upload image, directly send the keys.